# BCM2835_st_read() returns zero - confused

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

bcm2835 init works fine, as does all the GPIO & bcm2835_delay and the like.

RPi4 & Pi400, Raspbian "Bullseye", bcm2835 1.71, Libcap installed, added the program name etc

And I've compiled with Geany
gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -pthread $(pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs) -export-dynamic **-l bcm283**5 -l png **-DBCM2835_HAVE_LIBCAP**

Here's code:

```
// bcm_timer.c
//
// Example program for bcm2835 library system time

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <bcm2835.h>

uint64_t now = 0;
uint64_t then = 0;
uint rescode = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 
    // Init GPIO

    if ( ! bcm2835_init() )
    {
    printf("Fail 0x%X ", errno);
    return -1;
    }
   
    then = bcm2835_st_read();
   
    bcm2835_delay(500);
   
    now = bcm2835_st_read();    

    printf("Then = 0x%lluX, Now = 0x%lluX \n", then, now) ;
   
    bcm2835_close();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's output:

```
xxx@raspberrypi:~/Develop/c/test $ ./bcm_timer
Then = 0x0X, Now = 0x0X
```

Answer (score 1):

If you (or someone else) is still looking for the answer to this question, you need to run your code with sudo for bcm2835_st_read to work.

In my experiments, some things in the BME library require sudo (ran into this issue with i2c and the system timer), and some don't (gpio). Yes, it's annoying.

Hope this helps you or someone. -mg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).